# Test random numbers

Tags: java, c++, c, random, frequency

I have a random number generator. Now I just need to run three tests 
monobit test, runs test and the Chi square test. 
I am sure there are source codes available (in either of maybe c cpp or java) for these tests out there. Where can i find them?
that should save some time in writing them from scratch?

-

Answer (score 2):

This is what Google spat out for `chi square java`: [Class ChiSquareDist (Java Libraries for Stochastic Simulation)](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/probdist/ChiSquareDist.html)

The other two are fairly easy to code. Easier than to find, I'd say...